# Waching YouTube videos in bash sessions, in ASCII mode

Tags: terminal, tmux

I already found [how to watch YouTube videos in terminal, in ASCII mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/160212/45370), but my goal is to watch them in a bash session, without opening a different window.

So, supposing I already have a `tmux`  session, and I do:

```
$ watch-youtube <video-url>
```

I want to watch it there, in that `tmux` window/pane (split).

How can I do that?

---

Relevant output

```
$ mpv --vo help
Available video outputs:
  vdpau          : VDPAU with X11
  opengl         : Extended OpenGL Renderer
  xv             : X11/Xv
  sdl            : SDL 2.0 Renderer
  opengl-old     : OpenGL (legacy VO, may work better on older GPUs)
  vaapi          : VA API with X11
  x11            : X11 ( XImage/Shm )
  null           : Null video output
  image          : Write video frames to image files
  opengl-hq      : Extended OpenGL Renderer (high quality rendering preset)
  wayland        : Wayland SHM video output
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

libcaca will display in your current terminal if `$DISPLAY` is not set. So you can do something like:

```
DISPLAY= mpv --quiet -vo caca 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvYgBty6nJs'
```

The same trick works with mplayer, though it doesn't (AFAIK) have integrated libquvi support, so you have to extract the video URL to pass it.

Comment: Getting `[vo] Video output caca not found! Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.` -- only audio is working

Comment: @IonicăBizău is your mpv built without libcaca? Check `mpv --vo help` and see if its there. I'm using mpv 0.6, by the way.

Comment: Probably? See the update.

Comment: Yeah. So to use caca with mpv, you'd have to recompile it with caca support. Or use mplayer (if your mplayer has caca) as in the question you linked to. The key thing is that `DISPLAY= ` part, to keep it from popping up a new window.

Comment: Really awesome stuff here. It's working with `mplayer`, however `tmux` becomes unusable when such a process is running. Is there any way how to fix this?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Not sure. Works fine here in both screen and tmux... Though I'm on a fast machine. It does push the load average up to 2 or so when running mpv/caca in tmux...

Comment: I already have 5 tmux windows opened in the same terminal tab and maybe that's the thing... But even having just a split, it's very slow -- I mean, watching the video in the right side works fine, but in the left side I cannot do anything. I also have a powerful machine :-) Can you reproduce this with `mplayer`?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I even tried starting three videos in three different panes (tried with both mpv and mplayer1); using bash in a fourth was still just fine. Maybe it's your terminal emulator collapsing? I'm using xterm.

Comment: The latest command (on Mac, at least) is `mpv --vo=help`